# Unable to understand the pointer mechanism

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why is the program below crashing? I tried debugging the code but couldn't understand; I am suspecting that either the program is wrong or the memory to the passed pointer to `display` function should have been initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int display( int** intarray )
{
    int size = 0;
    while( size < 10 )
    {
        *intarray[size] = size;
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}

int main() {
    int* intptrarray;
    int arraysize = 0;
    arraysize = display( &intptrarray );

    for ( int indx = 0; indx < arraysize; indx++ )
    {
        std::cout << intptrarray[indx] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, undefined behavior by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Why are you even using pointers instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: Well, for sure you need to initialize the array somehow. And choose C or C++ but that code is not stylish at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*intarray[size]` should be `(*intarray)[size]`.

However you have not yet allocated any memory either, so in both cases you are causing undefined behaviour by writing through an uninitialized pointer.

A correct way to write this program is:

```
void display( std::vector<int> &vec )
{
    vec.resize(10);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        vec[i] = i;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    display(vec);

    for ( int indx = 0; indx < vec.size(); indx++ )
    {
        std::cout << vec[indx] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This can be improved by using `std::iota` and range-based for-loops if you have a modern compiler.

Comment: Even if I use `*intarray[size]` should be `(*intarray)[size]`. , it will still crash as the memory is uninitialized. Correct ?

Comment: It will cause undefined behaviour (which may result in a crash)

Comment: What would be the correct way to write the above program, I thought the below answer by @user3148225 was correct but its downvoted.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but still wanted the correct way using pointers only.

Answer (score 1):

When a pointer is declared, it doesn't point to any specific memory address.  To have it point somewhere, you need to allocate memory to it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int display( int** intarray, int arraysize )
{
    int size = 0;
    while( size < arraysize )
    {
        (*intarray)[size] = size;
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}

int main() {
    int arraysize = 10;
    int* intptrarray = new int[arraysize];

    arraysize = display( &intptrarray, arraysize );

    for ( int indx = 0; indx < arraysize; indx++ )
    {
        std::cout << intptrarray[indx] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] intptrarray;
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever you allocate memory, you need to remember to deallocate it yourself (delete for a single variable, delete[] for an array).